# Select distinct on multiple columns with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query below and it's selecting duplicate values from the database.

Is it possible to apply a `distinct` selection on multiple columns from two different tables?

```
SELECT m.ds_nome, a.cd_veiculo, a.dt_ini, a.dt_fim, a.cd_alerta, a.cd_motorista, a.ds_trata 
FROM alertas_jor AS a, motoristas AS m 
WHERE a.cd_motorista = m.cd_motorista AND m.cd_clifor IN(162) AND a.cd_tipo = 1

UNION

SELECT m.ds_nome, a.cd_veiculo, a.dt_ini, a.dt_fim, a.cd_alerta, a.cd_motorista, a.ds_trata 
FROM alertas_jor_hist AS a, motoristas AS m 
WHERE a.cd_motorista = m.cd_motorista AND m.cd_clifor IN(162) AND a.cd_tipo = 1
```

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates by default, so you shouldn't get any duplicate rows from this. You would only get duplicates with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: So I guess you mean that some columns are duplicated, but not the whole row. You need to use `GROUP BY` to combine them into a single row in the result.

Comment: Ok @Barmar. Thank you for your time!